# Relative javascript path do not work

Tags: javascript, path

I uploaded a simple angular 2 website to my ftp.

Strangely the relative paths don't work.

e.g. I have in myurl.de/subfolder/index.html

```
<script src="app/ext/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="app/ext/system-polyfills.js"></script>
...
```

And the browser searches the file in `myurl.de/app/ext/es6-shim.min.js` instead in `myurl.de/subfolder/ext/es6-shim.min.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of that would cause that would be a [`base` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element):

> The `base` element allows authors to specify the document base URL for the purposes of resolving relative URLs, and the name of the default browsing context for the purposes of following hyperlinks. The element does not represent any content beyond this information.

E.g., if you had something like this in the document

```
<base href="/">
```

That would change the base URL for the document such that the relative URLs would be calculated from there rather than the default base URL.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<script src="./ext/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="./ext/system-polyfills.js"></script>
```